# Display date in different languages

Tags: magento2, localisation, date, datetime

On our store we have a blog where we show the "`created_at`" date of the entity.
But we show the same post to 5 different languages. Of course the content is translated but we don't know how we should translate the date.

Currently we display it like this:

```
$date = date("d F, Y", strtotime($date)); // $date = 2019-04-16 08:45:25
echo "<span> " . $date . "</span>";
```

This outputs something like this:

[image]

Our main problem here is that the month is in english in all our languages. 
Is there a way to translate just the month?

PS: According to our PM just using the month number is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To format dates in other languages, you should use the `setlocale()` and `strftime()` functions.

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_TIME, "fr_FR"); // Here fr_FR is your translation locale
echo strftime("%d %B, %Y");
?>
```

Hope it finds helpful.

Comment: This function has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php

Answer (score 1):

The method strftime() is deprecated as of PHP 8.1.0. Relying on this function is highly discouraged. As alternative, we can use the following code.

```
<?php

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter('es_ES', IntlDateFormatter::LONG, IntlDateFormatter::NONE);
$dateTime = new DateTime('2022-01-30T15:09:09');
echo $formatter->format($dateTime);

//output: 30 de enero de 2022
```